# How does serde transform a the value inside a string into a Type

Tags: rust, serde

I've built an ECS (a simple one I think) and I've built a mechanism to load external data (entity templates) into my program the problem I'm having is how to transform the already loaded data into a type.

Since [Serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde) does this I thought to look up how but I can't actually find the part that does this.

What I mean is, when you create a data structure like this:

```
person:
  name: Bob
  age: 34
```

and serde is able to transform it into a struct:

```rust
struct Person {
   name: String,
   age: i32
}
```

How does serde transform the string `person` into the type `Person`

EDIT: 
To give an example in another language(ruby):

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
  def initialize(name:, age:)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
end

# pretend type was loaded in from the yaml example from the key
type = 'person'

# pretend person_data was loaded in from the yaml example form the value of the key
person_data = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 34
}

# and now we get the type and then initialize it
# Just like serde does
const_get(type.capitalize).new(person_data)
```

Now obviously Rust can't do this at runtime or does it like this but serde must do something to that ends up with the same result, with `"person"` transforming into `Person`.

Comment: "How does serde transform the string person into the type Person", serde don't do this maybe you mean [`serde-yaml`](https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-yaml)

Answer (score 1):

You tell serde the type you want. It knows the types of the members from the `Derive` implementation.

Comment: so how do I do this myself so I can derive the type `Person` from the string `person` as serde does?

Comment: serde doesn't derive the type Person from the string person.

Comment: So what, when you load the large string of textual data that is your data, serde changes `person` into `Person` magically without doing any processing or checking? It has to look at the data you've loaded to figure out what data is being loaded so it can take  `"person"` and return `Person` and then do some equivalent of `Person::new("Bob",34)` which then returns the final struct of `Person {name: "Bob", age: 34}`

Comment: @Thermatix You don't tell serde to "load this string". You tell it to "load a Person from this string" (or possibly "load a list of persons", or "load a Department" which contains persons). The top-level type to be loaded isn't derived from the data, it's statically written down in the code you write.